# Jumpy flag dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, flag-dialog

I have found a bug with the movement of the flagging dialog.

1. Click "flag" on my post.
2. Click "It doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate."
3. Move the flag dialog somewhere else.
4. Click "Flagging" (in the top left corner)
5. Notice that the flag dialog goes back to its original position.
6. Click "It doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate." again.
7. Notice that the flag dialog went back to the spot you moved it.
8. `GOTO 4`

Comment: Works in any order. Move, select option, move, select another option or go back > position shifts. The initial dialog and follow-up dialogs are different divs.

Comment: I made you a collage :) doesn't solve your problem, but until then you can keep staring at it :D http://i.stack.imgur.com/x1w0G.png

Comment: Sorry, don't think this is a bug. Personally don't see anything wrong with that behaviour.

Comment: @ShaWiz well, would you want your browser window to move every time you click "back?"

Comment: I didn't realise you could do step 3!

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it, whats your OS? Browsers type and version?

Comment: @Door it also "jump" back to the original position if you drag it, close it, then click "flag" link again. As Martjin pointed out, the "close as duplicate" is different dialog.

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Reproduced it with Chrome 25, Safari 6, and Firefox 19, all on Mac OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: The "I´m flagging..."- and "Flagging"-Dialog are two diffrent dialogs and each has its own position. Move the first dialog before you execute your Step 4.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Windows 7 Chrome 25.0.1364.97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really that flag reason is just a shortcut to closing, which is why you're seeing the dialogs "jump".

Starting with the next build, that transition will attempt to keep the dialogs in the same place.